# Gremlin PartitionStrategy PartitionKey vs WritePartition

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a question about partitionStrategy

```
const strategyA = new PartitionStrategy({ partitionKey: '_partition', writePartition: 'a', readPartitions: ['a'] });
const strategyB = new PartitionStrategy({ partitionKey: '_partition', writePartition: 'b', readPartitions: ['b'] });
const strategyC = new PartitionStrategy({ partitionKey: '_partition2', writePartition: 'b', readPartitions: ['b'] });
```

All 3 of these are "separate".  I notice that data is first split on partitionkey, then the partition itself.  I can read from partition A, and I'll receive the same data as long as the partitionKey is the same.

In my mind this is used sort of like

partitionKey = clientID
writePartition = ['uat', 'prod', ...]

However if I only need a 1-level key, it seems better to use separate partition keys for more guaranteed separation.

Is my understanding correct or is there some other reason partition strategy has both key+partition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `partitionKey` is only meant to specify the name of the property key in which to store the partition value. Perhaps a better name might have been "partitionKeyName" as that is more descriptive of what it's real usage is.

Generally speaking, you would have the same `partitionKey` for the entire graph. It's an interesting idea that you have where you could could effectively create wholly independent partitions by specifying multiple `partitionKey` values for the same graph. But then you are making partitions based on existence of a particular key on a graph and you would never be able to traverse the graph as a whole with `PartitionGraph`.